# How can I compare alpha channels pixel by pixel?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, channel

I've got two TIFF files with RGB and multiple alpha channels.  The RGB channels are pixel by pixel identical. The alpha channels have values from 0 to 255.  How can I compare an alpha channel in each file pixel by pixel?  I need some kind of way of clearly visualizing the differences.  The images are 300 x 384 pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say one file is called a.tif and the other b.tif.  The channels of interest are both called Alpha 1. Say we're working on Windows.

In a.tif

- Select Alpha 1 by clicking on channel in Channels window
- Select All (Ctrl-a)
- Copy (Ctrl-c)
- New File (Ctrl-n). Call this file c.tif
- In new file Paste (Ctrl-p) Call this layer A

In b.tif

- Select Alpha 1 by clicking on channel in Channels window
- Select All (Ctrl-a)
- Copy (Ctrl-c)
- In c.tif Paste (Ctrl-p) Call this layer B

In c.tif

- Right click on the top layer
- Blending options... | Difference

c.tiff will be completely black (value 0) for all pixels if layer A and B are identical.  You can check this either by scanning across with your mouse and using the Info window.  Or by applying Image|Auto contrast to each layer one at a time.